# Pass hidden variable or two variables with textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, hidden-field

In web programming it is very common to pass hidden variables or, using a select statement, show one variable such as someone's name while passing their id.  This is useful since using numerical ids, you get around problems of similar names, misspellings and so forth.

Is there any equivalent way to do this in iOS? In particular, I am using a subclass of textfield called `HTAutoCompleteTextField` to suggest names pulled from core data.  However, once the person selects the name, rather than store the name, I'd rather store the person's id for purposes of data integrity.

I know I can pull an array from core data that has both name and ID. I can show the name to the user. I just don't know how to store the id so that when the user picks the name, the id is passed back for saving.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's possible. When you create a user object you can link it to an objectId (maybe randomly generated string with a check to whether it is unique). You can also link the user object to a name.

The objectID is a great way to query and manage user objects.

With Parse.com's database for example, all created objects (or users) are given automatically generated objectIds.

Comment: I get that the user object can have a name and an ID.  However, if the user selects a person by their name, how would you capture the objected?

Comment: You can pass the user object they select and then look up user.objectId

Comment: If you are only given a name, you can query user objects that match the name, and from there you can retrieve the user.objectId

Comment: If you are given name john doe and there are two users John Doe and John  S. Doe, how would you keep track of userids?

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is when user selects something in an outlet, when you go to save, you get the value held by the property to which the outlet is wired.  Is there a way to keep track of userid when property value for namechanges so you can grab it when it comes time to save?